# What tools can i use to test the speed of communication between a server -> webserver -> client

Tags: mac, webserver, benchmark

in our company, we have to evaluate and compare the Mac Pro (2019) and the Mac mini (2018) in their usage as a client management server. 
We already know that the Mac Pro will be the better alternative/ upgrade to the now in use Mac mini (2012), but we still need to perform benchmark tests to further proof our standpoint to the department of finance. For that, i have already written several test scenarios.

Some background details: Our clients cant get any kind of updates via the app store. Every single update will go through a short evaluation from one of our team members, before building a package out of it, the server then distributes the update.

But for a few software titles, a webserver from the developer itself will contact our server, which then forwards the communication between the webserver and the client to distribute the udpdate. 
My colleague proposed a "simple webserver test". From that i take, that we need to test (1) the speed of our server to forward the communication between webserver and client and (2) the power of the webserver (?, if that is even possible for us).

I have some kind of experience with macOS in restricted enviroments like ours is, but no idea what to do with that webserver problem. To start, i searched the web for some tools, but could only find ones that could test your own webserver or just looking for the reachability of one.

Am i missing something? Did i just not realize what my colleague wanted (He's a really smart guy, but maybe he wasn't expressing himself right)? That is the only thing delaying the tests, but i dont want to steal everyones time with asking (simple) questions, where one could say that you should know this when working in IT, as we are loaded with other work right now.

Thanks i advance. Any tips, tricks, guides or tools are much appreciated! (I hope, that i tagged this question right)

Comment: Are you trying to measure the upload and download speed of the 2 different servers?

Comment: That is the point: I am not sure. In the end, that seems to be the right thing to do.